# Restrict the content in email notification from ElastAlert

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elastalert

Currently, I have setup email notification from elastalert. In the email body, it prints all the details of the particular document. I want to restrict it to print only specific term and values from the match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this question here: 
[Customize the information in an alert received by elastalert plugin for elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947201/customize-the-information-in-an-alert-received-by-elastalert-plugin-for-elastics)

Also from the [ElastAlert documentation](https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert#how-can-i-change-whats-in-the-alert), you can use `include:` field to customize the alert message..